# Inherit data from super class in android

Tags: java, android

Here is my example of inheritance activity. As the log shows I fail to get the correct data from my super class.

My super class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public String exampleString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NewButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            exampleString = "Test and test";    

            Log.e("Mytag", "here "+ exampleString);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);              
        }
    });



}
}
```

My sub class

```
public class Activity2 extends MainActivity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

        Log.e("Mytag", "here "+ exampleString);
}
}
```

My log

```
08-28 13:27:05.908: D/gralloc_goldfish(889): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-28 13:27:08.677: E/Mytag(889): here Test and test
08-28 13:27:09.408: E/Mytag(889): here null
```

Why does the sub class get the null value for exampleString?
Can any body help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you instantiate your superclass or any of its subclasses, you get a new instance of `exampleString`.

Make the variable static and then the classes will share it.

```
public static String exampleString;
```

However in your example it looks like you only want to send a string to another activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("myString", "my example argument");
intent.setClass(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and receive it in your other class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

    Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
    String example = args.getString("myString");
    Log.e("Mytag", "here " + example);
}
```

Activity2 will output: `here my example argument`

Comment: That's it. I am totally a newbe for java. Thank you mate

Comment: Thank you again. Yes this way saves the time for inheritance.

Comment: @WenhaoWu just remember to avoid using statics when you can :) They tend to lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the exampleString variable in the onClick method.

When you call the new activity in the onClick method, you're in fact creating a new instance of Activity2. Why should this new instance have a value in exampleString if you never set it there?

Inheritance is a good way to extend functionality and data from a super class to a sub class, but it by no means allows separate instances to share the same data.

Since in your second instance you never set the exampleText, your log print-out shows null.